# Using Single Python Def for Mulitple QpushButton base on Clicked

Tags: python, pyqt

I am doing a GUI with lots of buttons. With multiple selection option at a time.

I want to know how to connect a single Python Def for all buttons with `Clicked()` Button name as a arg?

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`QButtonGroup`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qbuttongroup.html) and its [`buttonClicked`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) signal. You'll get the `id` or the `QPushButton` itself.

**Edit**

A simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Arrange buttons horizontally
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        # QButtonGroup to keep track of buttons
        self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup()

        # Connect the 'buttonClicked' signal 'self.setLabel'
        # There are two overloads for 'buttonClicked' signal: QAbstractButton (button itself) or int (id)
        # Specific overload for the signal is selected via [QtGui.QAbstractButton]
        # Clicking any button in the QButtonGroup will send this signal with the button
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked[QtGui.QAbstractButton].connect(self.setLabel)

        for i in range(5): # Let's create 5 button
            button = QtGui.QPushButton('%d' % i)     # make a button
            buttonLayout.addWidget(button)           # add to layout
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)       # add to QButtonGroup
            #self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, i)    # You can give an 'id' if you like

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()  # just to write some output

        # lay everything out
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def setLabel(self, button):
        # clicking any button will call this slot 
        # 'button' argument will be the button itself
        # so... let's show its text in the label:
        self.label.setText('You clicked button with text "%s"' % button.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: thanks Avaris.. can u give a sample code with few buttons and with single Callback Fuction? becoz im new to Qt

Comment: @rishis3d: Sure, I've edited my answer with an example (hopefully with enough comment for you to figure out).

Comment: thanks for ur example code.. working fine.. how abt multiple selection at a time using "Shift" key?it could be very useful for my GUI.. im doing a character ctrl Selection GUI for Maya

Comment: @rishis3d: Multiple selection of what?

Comment: @Avaris..mutilple selection of buttons.. so i can grap mulitple objects using Shift key

Comment: @rishis3d: Perhaps you want checkable buttons?

Comment: @rishis3d: What you describe is a little difficult and sounds unintuitive to me. Maybe a "select all" and "clear" buttons would be better?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to create small functions - which can be lambdas, or objects as returned by functools.partial - that are connected to the actual Qt event. These mini-functions in turn, call your main callback, passing as many parameters as you like:

```
# coding: utf-8

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()
grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

def callback(button):
   print button

for x in range(10):
   b = QtGui.QPushButton()
   b.setText(unicode(x))
   grid.addWidget(b, 0, x)
   window.connect(b, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), (lambda y:lambda: callback(y) )(x))
   b.show()

window.setLayout(grid)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Notice you have to use an "enclosing lambda" for the actuall lambda which is the callback,
in order to "freeze" the value of x for each loop iteration.If the expression to the connect call where just `lambda: callback(x)`, x would be evaluated at keypress time, and would therefore be  `9`, in this case, for all buttons.

The main `callback` function, however, is just one, just as you asked for.

Comment: Imho your lambda expression is not very demonstrative. `lambda x: callback(x, a, b)` where `a` and `b` are variables from the global or local scope of the lambda definition.

Comment: And your lambda could be easily written `lambda: callback(x)` as well.

Comment: `lambda y=x: callback(y)` will _freeze_ the value of x. No need for the outer `lambda`. Although this works, I'd still go with `QButtonGroup` because of the convenience and more options.

Comment: @ Avaris and @jsbueno  thanks for ur example code guys.. both are working fine.. how abt multiple selection at a time using "Shift" key?it could be very useful for my GUI.. im doing a character ctrl Selection GUI for Maya